# UIActivityViewController: PostToTwitter: text can´t be changed in presented modal View

Tags: twitter, ios6, share

i have a problem with iOS 6´s UIActivityViewController. I want to share an image and a text. 
When i share it via Facebook, the text is editable in the modal view. In Twitter, i can't change the text. is there a way to change it for Twitter, so that the text is editable ?

This is my code:

```
    NSArray *activityItems =  @[@"Test Text",resultImage];

    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];

    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,UIActivityTypeMessage,UIActivityTypePostToWeibo];

    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Which SDK are you using, and are you doing anything that could cause this controller to be created off of the main thread?

Comment: I´m using iOS SDK 6.1.... 

I create the UIActivityViewController in an IBAction.... before i create it, i´m doing some image stuff... i also remove all the stuff inside the IBAction instead of the code, i posted above... but no improvement...i still can´t manipulate the text, when i try to share via Twitter...